# Code churn calculator (not for a version control system)

Tags: compare, code-metrics

Given two project versions, I would like to calculate code churn metrics.

EXAMPLE:

> Input: Two folders containing C and Header files of two versions of
>   the project

---

> Output: List of number of lines added/changed/removed in each file

I tried some tools, namely, [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=de). The problem was, the first required that the all files would be in the same directory, otherwise you can only compare them but get no metrics, the second was mainly a visualization tool, didn't give me metrics either.

Answer (score 2):

One of the tools you might consider is [WebDiff](http://java.uom.gr/~nikos/webdiff.html#Service)

Answer (score 1):

For .NET code such task can be achieved through a NDepend [Code Query LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) query such as (notice how you can choose code metrics):

```
from t in JustMyCode.Types
where t.IsPresentInBothBuilds() &&
      t.CodeWasChanged() // Only match types where code has been changed 
                         // between the two versions
let tOld = t.OlderVersion()
select new { t,
  newLoc = t.NbLinesOfCode,
  oldLoc = tOld.NbLinesOfCode,
  newNbMethods =t.Methods.Count(),
  oldNbMethods =t.Methods.Count(),
  newNbFields =t.Fields.Count(),
  oldNbFields =t.Fields.Count(),
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are your versions stored in a version control system (e.g., SVN, Git)? If yes, then you can compute your churn metrics by looking at the version control system log (which already gives lines added/changed/removed), even if the two versions are not consecutive commits.